# Returning result from Lambda function that executes Ruby script

Tags: node.js, ruby, lambda

I have followed along with an AWS [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/) which explains how to build a Lambda function that executes a Ruby script. My only confusion is how I return the result from the Ruby script as the result of the Lambda function.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    const child = exec('./lambdaRuby.rb ' + ''' + JSON.stringify(event) + ''', (result) => {
        // Resolve with result of process
        context.done(result);
    });

    // Log process stdout and stderr
    child.stdout.on('data', console.log);
    child.stderr.on('data', console.error);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just rewrite the logic in Ruby in NodeJS to save you all the hassle?

Comment: Because Lambda doesn't support Ruby natively and I am using a Ruby gem which is not ported to Node

Comment: I think you add another param to the handler function which is a callback .. see the example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial that you referenced is based on an old version of Node in Lambda.

If you use Node 6.10, it should be written as...

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    const child = exec(`./lambdaRuby.rb '${JSON.stringify(event)}'`, (error, stdout) => {
        if (error) return callback(error);

        return callback(null, stdout)
    });

    // Log process stdout and stderr
    child.stdout.on('data', console.log);
    child.stderr.on('data', console.error);
}
```

Comment: This answer does what you want which is to return the output of the script. If you want to use this with API Gateway though, you still have to change the structure of the response object.